# Blaze.renderWithData: how to reactively update the view when data changes?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

As the title states, how do I reactively update a view rendered by renderWithData when its relying data changes ?

Thanks ~

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using Tracker.autorun:

```
Tracker.autorun(function () {
   // get view and parentNode
   // fetch the data from a reactive source:
   var data = ...
   Blaze.renderWithData(view, data, parentNode);
});
```

When thee data changes, your autorun will be re-evaluated with the new data.